# On which basis does Israel designate NGOs as terrorist organizations?

Tags: israel, terrorism, human-rights, palestine, ngos

Recently Israel [designated several human rights NGOs as terrorist organizations](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2021/oct/22/israel-labels-palestinian-human-rights-groups-terrorist-organisations). The six organizations are alleged to have links to the PFLP:

> The Israeli defence ministry said they were linked to the Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine (PFLP), a secular political movement with an armed wing that in the past carried out attacks against Israel.

These organizations receive funding from various international sources:

> The groups, well known for their human rights work, have received funding from EU member states, the United Nations and other donors.

This designation is viewed as arbitrary by other human rights groups, for example B'Tselem:

> The Israeli human rights group B’Tselem called the government’s declaration “an act characteristic of totalitarian regimes, with the clear purpose of shutting down these organisations”.

It also seems to be viewed as arbitrary by some EU states, [for example Ireland](https://www.rte.ie/news/world/2021/1027/1256105-ngos-palestine/):

> Minister for Foreign Affairs Simon Coveney has expressed concern at the designation by Israel of six NGOs operating in the occupied Palestinian territories as terrorist entities. [..]
>
> He said no detailed evidence had been provided by Israel.
>
> In a statement Minister Coveney said previous allegations against civil society organisations in the territory have not been substantiated.

Apparently Israel provided no evidence that these NGOs are linked to terrorist activities. So on which basis (legal or judiciary process) was this designation made?

---

Edit August 2022: a [recent article in The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/22/cia-report-israel-palestinian-rights-groups) says that *"Earlier this year, Israel passed intelligence about the designation to the US, but a CIA intelligence assessment of the material did not find any evidence to support the claim, according to two sources familiar with the study."*

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Sorry but I rolled back your edit: I think the quotes and the questions raised by various organizations/countries about whether this decision was arbitrary are very important for the context of the question. The decision by Israel to label a well known NGO as terrorist  is not politically neutral: the fact that the decision is questionable from a democratic viewpoint is what makes it a political question imho.

Comment: IMO since it’s about the working of the Israeli government, it’s about politics either way, and the additional context just makes it seem like a [push question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-a-push-question). However, that’s just my opinion.

Comment: It's also the case for Turkey, Russia, the US or indeed the EU. You will find that labelling groups as terrorist is usually an intelligence matter rather than a judicial/legal process. I am not aware of any country that would make a comprehensive justification for these decisions publicly available. Even when a court has some say in it (like the EUCJ does), it only serves to reveal how opaque the process is and it is very difficult to provide an *effective* recourse.

Comment: @Relaxed of course, but the requirement for justification is higher when the designation as terrorist contradicts democratic values, at least in countries which aim to defend such values. Such arbitrary decisions from Turkey or Russia are not that surprising, but there would probably be some backlash if the US or the EU did this with a major NGO without providing any serious justification. Otherwise it's a backdoor for any arbitrary decision, for instance Israel could decide tomorrow to label the EU and the UN as terrorist as well, since they funded alleged terrorist organizations.

Comment: In practice that's exactly how it works. You might think they should be some serious justification but that's just not the case. Whether it's a violent group that seems obviously bad to you and me or some unknown organisation that hasn't been active for years and nobody cares about, there is no open process to lay out or dispute the evidence. As I said, it's a decision based on intelligence information that is deemed sensitive and not revealed to the public nor to the people or organisation impacted. I tend to agree that it feels arbitrary but that's just how it works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The designation was made by the Minister of Defence in accordance with Clause 3 of the [2016 Counter-Terrorism Law](https://www.justice.gov.il/En/Units/IMPA/MainDocs/The%20Counter%20Terrorism%20Law,%205776-2016.pdf):

> - (a)  Pursuant to this Article, the Minister of Defense may designate, by order, a body of persons as a  terrorist organization,
>   once he is convinced that paragraph (1) or (2) of the definition
>   "terrorist  organization" applies, and that it has a connection to
>   Israel.
> - (b)  The designation of a terrorist organization shall be based upon a reasoned written request from  the Head of the Israel Security
>   Agency, or from the head of another Defense Authority, submitted  by
>   the Head of the Israel Security Agency together with his opinion –
>   [ether requests being]  subject to the approval of the Attorney
>   General. In the request, the Head of the Defense Authority  shall
>   specify the information and facts on which he is basing his position
>   that subsection (a)  applies with respect to the body of persons.
> - (c)  With regard to a terrorist organization according to paragraph (2) of the definition "terrorist  organization" that is acting in
>   Israel through a party operating on its behalf—the Head of the
>   Defense Authority shall only submit a request mentioned in subsection
>   (b) after warning has  been provided to the organization and it has
>   continued its activity, provided that he [the Head of  the Defense
>   Authority] has determined that such a warning will not thwart the
>   possibility of  taking action against the organization.

The definition of terrorist organization referred to is:

> 1. A body of persons in an organized and continuous structure that
>    commits terrorist acts  or that operates with the intention that
>    terrorist acts will be committed — including an  aforementioned body
>    of persons that is engaged in training or instruction for the
>    commission of terrorist acts, or that carries out an act  involving
>    weapons or performs a  weapons transaction, in order to carry out
>    terrorist acts—whether or not it has been  designated as a terrorist
>    organization pursuant to Part B;
> 2. A body of persons in an organized and continuous structure that
>    acts, directly or  indirectly, to assist an organization mentioned in
>    paragraph (1), or that acts with the  intention of promoting the
>    activity of such an organization, including by financing it – all  of
>    the foregoing, in a manner capable of making a substantial or ongoing
>    contribution to  the organization's activity, or [where such body of
>    persons] has a substantial affiliation  to [the organization],
>    provided that the body of persons [defined in this paragraph] has
>    been designated as a terrorist organization pursuant to Part B;

The designation orders themselves are linked at the bottom of the [National Bureau for Counter Terror Financing of Israel (NBCTFI) press release](https://nbctf.mod.gov.il/en/Pages/211021EN.aspx), and contain a limited justification for the designation. For example, the [designation order for the Union Of Agricultural Work Committees](https://nbctf.mod.gov.il/he/Announcements/Documents/Designation%20No.%20371-%20Union%20Of%20Agricultural%20Work%20Committees%20_22.10.21.pdf) reads:

> 1. The  Union  of  Agricultural  Work  Committees was established in  1986  and  became  an  arm  of  the  "Popular  Front  for  the
>    Liberation  of  Palestine"  in Judea and  Samaria  and in the Gaza
>    Strip.
> 2. The institution's base is in  Ramallah. According to its  declaration,  the  Union  is  engaged  in assistance to Palestinian
>    farmers  and furthering agricultural research  and development
>    projects. In  practice,  it  promotes  activity  that  serves the
>    "Popular Front"  objectives.
> 3. The Union, together with  additional "Popular Front"  organizations,  acted  in  forgery  and  deceit vis-à-vis many
>    European  countries and international  organizations  to  obtain
>    financing,  which in practice reached the  Popular Front" terror
>    activity.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. The provided justification is very vague indeed. I'm curious in particular about the timing: do you know by any chance if any event or investigation caused the change?

Comment: @Erwan The NBCTFI press release mentions the trigger as the conclusion of a joint investigation between themselves and the GSS that began in 2021 - I'm not sure if any more detailed information has been made available.

Comment: @Erwan I think "became an arm of" a designated terrorist organization is quite specific. As for the "why now" question, I can't say for sure, but in the case of the UAWC, [it might be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_of_Agricultural_Work_Committees#Affiliate_of_PFLP) related to the financing of terrorists that murdered a 17 year old in 2019.

Comment: @tim unless this organization has official links to the PFLP, "became an arm of" is an unsubstantiated interpretation. There might be some specific evidence behind this claim, but it's not provided in this document.

Comment: There's nothing vague about that justification. You can argue that it's unsubstantiated instead. In practice, these decisions will be made based on information from the Israeli intelligence apparatus, which means we *don't know* why. I'd argue that by the same principle, any organization being designated as terrorist without they themselves explicitly confirming it is just as unsubstantiated.

Comment: In practice any country can use this kind of legislation as a "punish anyone who criticizes us" law.  Israel seems to be one country where that abuse is barely concealed.  It's an interesting question to ask if the same laws applied to NGOs that overtly support Israel would also (if applied equally) would label many of them as terrorists.

Comment: @Gloweye why I think it's vague: "promotes activity that serves the "Popular Front" objectives" could mean anything, from directly recruiting for or funding the FPLP to simply helping Palestinian farmers, some of whom might be involved with the FPLP. Both "serve the FPLP objectives", but the degree of involvement is very different. Same thing for "became an arm of": does this mean that the whole NGO staff was knowingly under the chain of command of the FPLP, that some FPLP people were covertly infiltrated, or that a few employees happen to be active FPLP members?

Comment: Claims of terrorism do not have to be substantiated because the end goal isn't to combat terrorism, it's to punish any resistance and to create insufferable conditions. [The USA does the same thing, just FYI.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJJkaWVENTg)

Comment: @Erwan Much of the information is in the public domain, and can be seen at https://www.ngo-monitor.org/reports/pflp-ties-six-newly-designated-terror-ngos/ The staff linked to the PFLP are generally founders, directors, and other high ranking officials within the NGO.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The link you posted leads to the current page. But if you want to see what "punish[ing] any resistance and creat[ing] insufferable conditions" truly looks like, see https://www.gatestoneinstitute.org/17913/palestinian-authority-ngos

Comment: @ZevSpitz the Gatestone Institute is not a trustworthy source at all. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatestone_Institute): "Gatestone is an anti-Muslim group. The organization has attracted attention for publishing false or inaccurate articles, some of which were shared widely".

Comment: @ZevSpitz the NGO monitor link is more informative. Imho it's still very weak evidence: for example I looked at the evidence for the UAWC, it mentions only an old document from 1993, and a few events between 2010 and 2014 that some FPLP members attended. It also raises the question of why the designation was made recently: if this evidence is considered sufficient, the organization should have been designated illegal years ago. If not, it means that either there is some additional evidence that is not public, or that it's a political decision.